# Quotient module for the regular representation of the cyclic group of order 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

Consider the regular representation $V$ of the cyclic group of order 3, $G=\{ e,a,a^2\}$, with the standard basis $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3\}$. Consider then another basis given by
$$\tag{1}
(\textbf{v}_1\textbf{u}_1,\textbf{u}_2):=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\textbf{e}_1+\textbf{e}_2+\textbf{e}_3),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\textbf{e}_1-\textbf{e}_2), \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(\textbf{e}_1+\textbf{e}_2-2\textbf{e}_3)\right),
$$
where $\{ \mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2 \}$ defines a basis for a submodule $U$ of $V$. Now, $G$ clearly acts trivially on the $G$-module spanned by $\mathbf{v}_1$, so the representation of that submodule is the $1\times 1$ identity matrix. Is the same true for the quotient module, $V/U$?

**Edit:** the representation of the group with the above basis is
$$\tag{2}
            \sigma(e)= 
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\
                0 & 1 & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 1
            \end{bmatrix},
            \qquad \sigma(a)=
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0                   & 0 \\
                0 & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
                0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & -\frac{1}{2}
            \end{bmatrix},
            \qquad \sigma\left(a^2\right)=
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0                   & 0 \\
                0 & -\frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
                0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
            \end{bmatrix}.
$$
According to *Algebra* by P.M. Cohn, if $V'$ is a submodule of a module $V$ and the basis $\{ \mathbf{v}_1,...,\mathbf{v}_f \}$ is written such that the last members form a basis for $V'$, then the representation for $V$ takes the form:
$$
\rho(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\rho''(x)&\theta(x)\\ 0&\rho'(x)\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\rho'(x)$ is a representation for $V'$ and $\rho''$ a representation for the quotient module $V/V'$. With this in mind, I would assume that the upper $1\times 1$ matrix of eq. $(2)$ is a representation for $V/U$. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: An arbitrary element of $V/U$ has the form $\lambda_1 v_1+\mu_1 u_1+\mu_2u_2+U$.  If you apply $g\in G$ to this element, do you get the same element back?

Comment: @tkf, no, because $g$ does not act trivially on $u_1$ and $u_2$. But then what am I misunderstanding with respect to what Cohn writes (see my edit)?

Comment: If you look at the difference between the original element and $g$ applied to the element, you get $$\mu_1u_1+\mu_2u_2-\mu_1(u_1 g)-\mu_2(u_2)g+U=0+U.$$ Note for any $u\in U$ we have $$u+U=0+U.$$

Comment: @tkf, so it is the same because $g$ acting on $U$ is contained in $U$? And since $g$ also acts trivially on $v_1$, it acts trivially on an arbitrary element in $V/U$.

Comment: Yes exactly - that is why it works.  Your matrix interpretation is perfectly correct too.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for helping out.